# RecyclerView no me muestra nada

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview

Estoy trabajando con RecyclerView y con bases de datos SQLite para que muestre los datos de la base de datos en la pantalla del móvil, pero no sé por qué no se me muestra nada en la pantalla. Ya me he asegurado de que los datos se están recogiendo. Lo que hago es pasar los datos de la BD a objetos y creo un arrayList con esos objetos pero en pantalla no se ve nada. Este es mi código.

Main:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
// Creación
lateinit var miButtonConsultar: Button
lateinit var miRecycler: RecyclerView
lateinit var adapter: PreguntasAdapter
lateinit var listaPreguntas: ArrayList<Preguntas>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
    // Inicialización de elementos.
    miButtonConsultar = findViewById(R.id.buttonConsulta)
    miRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    listaPreguntas = ArrayList<Preguntas>()
    
    // Configuración del recycler
    miRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    miRecycler.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
    
    // Inicialización del adapter
    adapter = PreguntasAdapter(applicationContext, listaPreguntas, this@MainActivity::onItemClickHandler)
    
    // Función que convierte a objetos los elementos de la base de datos y los mete en la lista
    llenarLista()
    }
 
    /**
     * Función que convierte a objetos los elementos de la base de datos y los mete en la lista
     */
    private fun llenarLista(){
            // Conexión con la base de datos
            val admin = DBHelper(this)
            val db = admin.writableDatabase
            // Cursor donde se almacenan datos
            val cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Preguntas Order by Id desc", null)
            
            // Limpiamos la lista en caso de que contenga algo
            listaPreguntas.clear()

            // Se van convirtiendo los datos de la base de datos a objetos y se añaden a la lista
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    var id: Int = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id").toInt()).toInt()
                    var pregunta: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pregunta").toInt())
                    var respuesta1: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta1").toInt())
                    var respuesta2: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta2").toInt())
                    var respuesta3: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta3").toInt())
                    var respuesta4: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta4").toInt())
                    var respuestaCorrecta: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("RespuestaCorrecta").toInt())

                    val preguntaObject: Preguntas = Preguntas(id, pregunta, respuesta1, respuesta2, respuesta3, respuesta4, respuestaCorrecta)

                    Log.i(preguntaObject.toString(), "cosa")
                    Toast.makeText(this, preguntaObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    listaPreguntas.add(preguntaObject)
                }while(cursor.moveToNext())
            }

            // Notificar al adapter que hay cambios
            if (listaPreguntas.size > 0){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        
            // Cerramos conexiónes
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
        }

    private fun onItemClickHandler(position: Int){
        
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class PreguntasAdapter (var context: Context, var listaPreguntas: ArrayList<Preguntas>, val itemClickHandler: (Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<PreguntasAdapter.PreguntasViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener{
class PreguntasViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    // Inicialización de los elementos
    var miTextViewPregunta: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemPregunta)
    var miTextViewRespuesta1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemRespuesta1)
    var miTextViewRespuesta2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemRespuesta2)
    var miTextViewRespuesta3: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemRespuesta3)
    var miTextViewRespuesta4: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemRespuesta4)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PreguntasViewHolder {
    var v: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_preguntas, parent, false)

    var viewHolder = PreguntasViewHolder(v)

    return PreguntasViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreguntasViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val preguntaObject: Preguntas = listaPreguntas.get(position)

    var pregunta: String = preguntaObject.pregunta
    var respuesta1: String = preguntaObject.respuesta1
    var respuesta2: String = preguntaObject.respuesta2
    var respuesta3: String = preguntaObject.respuesta3
    var respuesta4: String = preguntaObject.respuesta4

    holder.miTextViewPregunta.setText("$pregunta")
    holder.miTextViewRespuesta1.setText("$respuesta1")
    holder.miTextViewRespuesta2.setText("$respuesta2")
    holder.miTextViewRespuesta3.setText("$respuesta3")
    holder.miTextViewRespuesta4.setText("$respuesta4")
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listaPreguntas.size
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

}

Gracias de antemano, si necesitan más info en concreto se lo digo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lo inicializas, pero nunca le seteas tu lista de objetos a tu adapter, por eso no te muestra nada
>
> Aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```
 private void setAdapterPreguntas() {
    if (preguntasAdapter == null){
        preguntasAdapter = new PreguntasAdapter(listaPreguntas,this@MainActivity::onItemClickHandler);
        miRecycler.setAdapter(preguntasAdapter);
    }else {
        preguntasAdapter.setPreguntas(listaPreguntas);
        preguntasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

> **setPreguntas(listaPreguntas)** es un método que debes colocar en tu adapter

```
public void setPreguntas(ArrayList<Preguntas> preguntas) {
    this.listaPreguntas= preguntas;
}
```

> Lo puedes mandar a llamar, dentro de tu **onCreate()**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setAdapterPreguntas()

}
```

Comment: Genial, me ha funcionado. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Excelente, alguien una vez me dijo: "Hay veces que los árboles no nos dejan ver el bosque".